# To whom does "author" refer when using schema.org's "MusicAlbum" schema?

Tags: best-practice

I am trying to encode reviews of music albums. If I understand the "MusicAlbum" schema correctly, the =reviewer= is the "author" of the "review" content? Can anyone point me to examples of well-constructed reviews (MusicAlbum" or otherwise)? Likewise, what is the best way to note the language in which the MusicAlbum is recorded--in my case, often not the same as the language of the review?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to think that the *reviewer* would be the **Author** according to the **[Review](https://schema.org/Review)** schema. The [MusicAlbum](https://schema.org/MusicAlbum) schema specifies that the **inLanguage** value regards the language in which the music was recorded.

Here's an example I quickly threw together that might explain how you can implement a Review into a Music Album:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "MusicAlbum",
  "byArtist": {
    "@type": "MusicGroup",
    "name": "Radiohead"
  },
  "genre": "Alt/Punk",
  "image": "king-of-limbs.jpg",
  "name": "King of Limbs",
  "numTracks": "8",
  "track": [
    {
      "@type": "MusicRecording",
      "duration": "PT5M14S",
      "name": "Bloom",
      "url": "/artist/radiohead/album/the-king-of-limbs/track/bloom"
    },
    {
      "@type": "MusicRecording",
      "duration": "PT4M40S",
      "name": "Morning Mr Magpie",
      "url": "/artist/radiohead/album/the-king-of-limbs/track/morning-mr-magpie"
    }
  ],
  "url": "/artist/radiohead/album/the-king-of-limbs",
    "inLanguage": "english",
    "review": [
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Reviewer Bob",
            "datePublished": "2015-11-30",
            "description": "Writing a review for Stack Exchange",
            "name": "Satisfied user",
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that makes perfect sense. I'm seeing JSON-LD? I have an example I've been working on using microdata that looks something like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <a itemprop="url" href="could be link to purchase point?"><div itemprop="name"><strong>Some Band / Some new album</strong></div></a>
    <div itemprop="description">brand new country-western album</div>
    <div itemprop="reviewBody">this is really good</div>
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        Written by: <span itemprop="name">reviewer Ari</span></div> ##no need to dive into FOAF-related stuff for now
    <div><meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-11-30">Date published: 11/30/2015</div>
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0"><span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> / <span   itemprop="bestRating">5</span> stars</div>

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicAlbum">
        <div itemprop="name"> King of Limbs 
            <meta content="Alt/Punk" itemprop="genre" /></div>
        <div itemprop="byArtist" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicGroup">
            <span itemprop="name">Radiohead</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```